# Best way to remove dropouts from sensor time history data in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, filtering, signal-processing

I am currently trying to find the best way to remove sensor dropouts from time history data. Sensor dropouts may occur due to EMI or other interference in wireless data transmission. When a dropout occurs, the data "rails" to a certain low value, but I would like to keep it arbitrary such that the user does not need to know that value. There may be several datapoints on the way down to the low value, as well as on the way back up.

Ideally, I would like to be able to detect these dropouts, remove them, and fill them using a similar function to MATLAB's "fillgaps". I have added an arbitrary example of what a sensor dropout may look like below.

So far, I have tried using a median filter, as well as a moving window standard deviation filter, however these methods did not achieve the results I am looking for.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
y = 5 * np.sin((x - 20)/20) + np.sin(x)
idx = [np.random.randint(0,len(y)) for _ in range(5)]
for i in idx:
    y[i:i+10] = -30
    y[i-2] = -10
    y[i-1] = -20
    y[i+10] = -20
    y[i+11] = -10
    
plt.plot(x,y,linestyle='-',marker='o')
plt.show()
```

[image: Sensor Dropout Example]

Comment: In what way did the median filter and moving window standard deviation filter not achieve the wanted results?

Comment: Would your user know the general range of the data (i.e. "if the data is generally between -5 and +5, anything below -10 or above +10 is bad"), or would you need to fully autonomously find the anomalies?

Comment: Ideally it would be fully autonomous, as it will be used for many different types of sensors with different data ranges. Also, as I mentioned sometimes there are data points on the way down to and back up from the "low" value, so sometimes these points are still within the valid data range, but still need to be removed.

Comment: The moving window standard deviation filter works well for single point transients, but for longer dropouts like this, the dropouts bring the mean of the window down too much. The median filter seems to truncate peaks in the "good" data rather than just removing transients. The good data needs to remain untouched.

Comment: I think the moving window standard deviation filter should work well. If you remove the bad point before they enter the window, the mean shouldn't go down